# Beamer: Problem With Capital Greek Letters

Tags: beamer, greek, uppercase

I am using beamer and the capital greek letters are displayed as black boxes.
I have found this error in other questions but none of the answers worked for me.
Here is the code

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{mathabx} % conflict with amssymb 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
 \titles{Propositional Logic}{}
  \begin{small}
   foo $\gamma$ $\Gamma$
  \end{small}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It compiles fine with me, could you provide the log file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The only problem is the `\titles` command. I supposed you meant `\frametitle` and it compiles fine.

Comment: Does it also fail with other documentclasses, for example `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}foo $\gamma$ $\Gamma$\end{document}`?

Comment: @Bernard Even in if erase de `\titles` the black box is there. This problem is only when using beamer @Marijn

Comment: It is probably the combination of other packages, the code I put here does not show all the packages and commands.

Comment: You should comment all unnecessary packages with this code, then gradually uncomment them until you detect which package (or combination of packages) is responsible for this (proceeding by dichotomy will make it faster if there are many packages).

Comment: The math packages are ok, the problem is the use of charter and lmodern packages. 
Thanks @Bernard! Thanks all!